# ItemIgnoresTransformation flag results in shifted item when scaling

Tags: python, c++, qt, pyqt, qgraphicsitem

I have a QGraphicsRectItem object, `box` placed on a scene, which is a parent to a QGraphicsEllipseItem object, `circle` that is placed on the bottom right hand corner via `circle.setPos(box.rect().bottomRight())` in the overriden `paint` method of the QGraphicsRectItem:

[image]

I am trying to prevent the QGraphicsEllipseItem from changing size when the view is scaled by setting the `QGraphicsItem.ItemIgnoresTransformations` flag. This however causes the placement of this item relative to its parent to be shifted when the view is scaled i.e.:

[image]

How can I prevent the QGraphicsEllipseItem from scaling yet keep its position relative to the parent intact?

Comment: How do you set position of the ellipse item?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. See edit. I also tried reimplementing the `itemChange` method of the rect item to reposition the ellipse item if an `ItemScaleChange` is detected. Got the same result as scaling the view doesn't affect the the items in the scene.

Comment: Are your ellipse coordinates centered around (0, 0)?